# why layered navigation shopping option BRAND not working?

Tags: php, magento

[image: image describes the error]

I added custom attribute `brand` and i want that brand to be in layered navigation to filter the products by brand. But as in the attached picture its not create links for brand section and not showing the total number of products for each brand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to goto `"Frontend properties"` of `attributes` and set

`Use In Layered Navigation` to `YES`.

Also you have to set `is Anchor` `YES` for that `category`.

And also the `category should have some products with brand value`.

Comment: seems like all are oky.  But i have set `Filterable (no results)` instead of `Filterable (with results)` . And 2 products from brand2 and other 2 products from brand1 and brand9 .

Comment: what filterable(no results) ??

Comment: edit attribute then under `Use In Layered Navigation`